# What is "+0" in a simple mixed model code (R)?

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models

I'm trying to compare a difference I encountered in mixed model analyses using the package lme4. Maybe my statistical background is not sharp enough but I just can't figure what the "+0" in the code is and what the resulting difference (to a model without +0) implies.

Here my example with the +0:

```
lmer(Yield ~ Treatment + 0 + (1|Batch) + (1|Irrigation), data = D)
```

in contrast to:

```
lmer(Yield ~ Treatment  + (1|Batch) + (1|Irrigation), data = D)
```

Does anyone have a smart explanation for what the +0 is and what it does to the results?

Answer (score 1):

Models with `+ 0` usually mean "without an overall intercept" (in the fixed effects). By default, models have an intercept included, you can also make that explicit using `+ 1`.

Most discussions of regression modelling will recommend including an intercept, unless there's good reason to believe the outcome will be 0 when the predictors are all zero (maybe true of some physical processes?).

Compare:

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + 0 + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
summary(fm1)
summary(fm2)
```

paying attention to the fixed effects

Comment: Also, in many cases, fitting without intercept (`+ 0`) allows us to build simpler and more intuitive contrasts in, say, ANOVA.

Comment: "unless there's good reason to believe the outcome will be 0 when the predictors are all zero" Even then it's often better to include the intercept in order to have an appropriate resulting error model.